# Drupal 6: how can I translate profile fields found in Ubercart checkout pane?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I was wondering how could I translate the profile fields which I included in my checkout pane. I am using drupal 6 and Ubercart.

What is most bizarre about the thing is that I have the internationalization module enabled and have translated the profile fields. These appear as translated in my user's edit profile(user/id/edit). The checkout pane still displays the original text.

Answer (score 0):

Entering translations for these fields wonèt work. You need to download and import the Ubercart translation package that suits your needs - http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=ubercart